# add newlines or line breaks after p closing tag with php

Tags: php, regex

I have this text in a MySql database:

```
First paragraph very long.
Second paragraph very long.
Third paragraph.
```

I add p tags and it works:

```
$text = preg_replace("/\n/","<p>",$text);
$text = '<p>'.$text;
```

I try to add line breaks when I echo to a html page. I tried 3 different things. But none of them seem to work:

```
$text = preg_replace("/<\/p>/","</p>\n\n",$text);
$text = preg_replace("/<\/p>/","</p><br><br>",$text);
$text = nl2br($text);
echo $text;
```

If I go to the web inspector in the Safari browser, I get this:

```
<p>First paragraph very long.</p><p>Second paragraph very long.</p><p>Third paragraph.</p>
```

I would like to have this:

```
<p>First paragraph very long.</p>\n>\n
<p>Second paragraph very long.</p>\n>\n
<p>Third paragraph.</p>\n>\n
```

It seems that my regex does not select `<\/p>` even when I escape it. I do not understand. What is wrong?

Comment: Please check [this demo](https://ideone.com/AaH4wD) - I wrote it when you first posted this question some hours ago. The point is that you do not really add any `</p>` tags.

Comment: `nl2br` will [replace linebreaks with `<br/>` tags](https://ideone.com/AaH4wD).

Comment: @Wiktor: Yes! yours works very well. Any idea why my regex does not work, what is wrong?

Comment: `<\n>` is not a **TAG**

Comment: I said you do not have `</p>` inside the string, thus, there is nothing to replace.

Comment: @Wiktor: post your answer and I will accept it. You say that I did not have </p> tags but when I go to the web inspector I see them.

Comment: Well, look at the answers below, maybe they are good enough to accept. I am not sure you really need a regex here.

Comment: Just a note, @WiktorStribiżew is correct about your lack of closing p tags. As to why you are seeing them, `inspect element` shows the generated DOM, eg **AFTER** the browser has tried to fix any irregularities. Right click and select 'view source' to see you mangled html in all its unadulterated glory

Comment: @segon your `preg_replace` works as expected (I have tested): maybe your text is not as you think. Try to show-it through `htmlentities()` to see if is correct: maybe Safari correct the code (?)

Comment: @segon Yes, Safari change your html. I tried a page with `<p>` without closing `</p>` and Inspector show `<p></p>` anyway

Comment: @u-mulder: you are right. I corrected my question. It was not the problem but it was a mistake. Thank you

Comment: @segon if my answer doesnt help you, please explain why. You need to give feedback if you want help on here.

Comment: @Steve: Yes, your answer helps. Sorry for the delay. I have been testing all this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Presuming you need newline control chars (and not html line break tags):

```
$text = "First paragraph very long.\nSecond paragraph very long.\nThird paragraph.";
$text = '<p>' . preg_replace("~\n~", "<p>\n\n</p>", trim($text)) . '</p>;
```

Note `trim` is used incase you have leading or trailing newlines, `~` is used as a delimiter, because `/` is a poor choice when dealing with html, causeing you to escape all over the place.

It is not apparent in the above example, but using some of your reqex as an example:

```
preg_replace("~</p>~","</p>\n\n",$text);
```

is much easier to read than:

```
preg_replace("/<\/p>/","</p>\n\n",$text);
```

Also, you dont need regex, you could just use `str_replace`:

```
$text = '<p>' .str_replace("\n", "<p>\n\n</p>", trim($text)) . '</p>;
```

Or even explode/implode:

```
$text = '<p>' . implode("</p>\n\n<p>", explode("\n", trim($text))) . '</p>';
```

If it was html line breaks you wanted, then you could just edit the replacement argument to:

```
"</p><br><br><p>"
```

in any of the above, but it would probably be better to use some css:

```
p{
    margin-bottom:10px;
}
```

Comment: what is "~" why is it needed

Comment: `~` Is used as a delimeter: http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php  in the same way your code uses `/`. As delimiters must be escaped in the enclosed regex, using `/` in a regex targeting html is a bad idea, because `/` crops up in html all the time, meaning you have to fill your regex full of backslashes to escape them

Answer (score 2):

You don't need regex, simple `str_replace` works (in your example):

```
$text = str_replace( "</p><p>","</p>\n<p>",$text );
```